# How do I hide a login form if user is logged in?

Tags: form, conditional

What conditional statement would hide a form if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Twig variable [`currentUser`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables#currentUser) contains information about the currently logged in user, and will be *null* if no user is currently logged in.

```
{% if not currentUser %}

    <!-- Your login form -->

{% endif %}
```